# Проблема с ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Есть код, но firebug выдает ошибку. В javascript не силен, прошу помочь решить проблему

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function post(id)
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_send.php",
    data: "id=" + id,
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
</script>  
<a href="javascript:post('1');">Добавить 1</a>
<a href="javascript:post('2');">Добавить 2</a>
<a href="javascript:post('3');">Добавить 3</a>
<a href="javascript:post('4');">Добавить 4</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

забыл про фигурные скобки

```
function post(id){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_send.php",
    data: "id=" + id,
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: да, в функции после условия должны быть фигурные скобки это синтаксическая ошибка у тебя!